# Android Firebase - Updating new image to current user stops the application (not crash)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I was trying to change profile picture by clicking an imageview and I was able to crop the image then store into my Firebase storage. But, when the new image file is added, the program stops and cant click anything. App is not even crashing nor turned off. and when I see my android monitor it is keep printing something out nonstop. I think this goes into some sort of infinite loop somewhere. Does anyone recognize the problem?

P.S. When I update new profile image, I see that the `image` child under my User in my Firebase database changes really fast, back and forth. If the previous image is "1" and the image I updated is "2", it goes 1->2->1->2->1->2.. like crazy. They swap each other very fast

MyProfileActivity.java

```
public class MyProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    /*UI*/
    private Toolbar mMyProfileToolbar;
    private TextView mAge;
    private TextView mGender;
    private TextView mReligion;
    private TextView mSports;
    private TextView mState;
    private TextView mTimeRegistered;
    private TextView mDisplayName;
    private CircleImageView mProfileImage;

    /*Firebase*/
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUser;
    private FirebaseUser mUser;
    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabasePost;
    private StorageReference filepath;
    private DatabaseReference user_db;

    /*Other*/
    private String age;
    private String gender;
    private String religion;
    private String sports;
    private String state;
    private String timeRegistered;
    private String displayName;
    private String image;
    private Uri mImageUri = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_profile);

        /*UI*/
        mMyProfileToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.activity_my_profile_toolbar);
        mProfileImage = (CircleImageView)findViewById(R.id.activity_my_profile_profile_image);
        mDisplayName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.activity_my_profile_display_name);
        mAge = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.activity_my_profile_age);
        mGender = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.activity_my_profile_gender);
        mReligion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.activity_my_profile_religion);
        mSports = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.activity_my_profile_sports);
        mState = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.activity_my_profile_state);
        mTimeRegistered = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.activity_my_profile_time_registered);

        /*Firebase*/
        mDatabaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");
        mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        /*Function*/
        setSupportActionBar(mMyProfileToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);

        mDatabaseUser.child(mUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                displayName = dataSnapshot.child("displayName").getValue().toString();
                age = dataSnapshot.child("age").getValue().toString();
                gender = dataSnapshot.child("gender").getValue().toString();
                religion = dataSnapshot.child("religion").getValue().toString();
                sports = dataSnapshot.child("sports").getValue().toString();
                state = dataSnapshot.child("state").getValue().toString();
                timeRegistered = dataSnapshot.child("timeRegistered").getValue().toString();

                image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                Picasso.with(MyProfileActivity.this).load(image).into(mProfileImage);

                mDisplayName.setText(displayName);
                mAge.setText("Age: " + age);
                mGender.setText("Gender: " + gender);
                mReligion.setText("Religion: " + religion);
                mSports.setText("Sports: " + sports);
                mState.setText("State: " + state);
                mTimeRegistered.setText("Time Registered: " + timeRegistered);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
            {

            }
        });

        mProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            mImageUri = data.getData();

            CropImage.activity(mImageUri)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.OFF)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(this);
        }
        if(requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                mImageUri = result.getUri();

                mProfileImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);

                filepath = mStorage.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Profile_Images").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

                filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
                    {
                        final Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                        Toast.makeText(MyProfileActivity.this, "You added picture successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mDatabaseUser.child(mUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(MyProfileActivity.this, "Changing picture now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                DatabaseReference user_db = mDatabaseUser.child(mUser.getUid());
                                user_db.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                            {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            else if(resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE)
            {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app is looping in the code shown below.  You add a listener to location `mDatabaseUser.child(mUser.getUid())`.  When the data at that location changes, `onDataChange()` runs and performs a `setValue()` for child `image` of location `mDatabaseUser.child(mUser.getUid())`. Although you are only changing a child of the location, it is considered a change to the parent location, causing the listener to fire again, setting the value again, and so on, endlessly.

```
mDatabaseUser.child(mUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MyProfileActivity.this, "Changing picture now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        DatabaseReference user_db = mDatabaseUser.child(mUser.getUid());
        user_db.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
    {

    }
});
```

You also have two listeners on the same location, the one shown above and the second in the `onCreate()` method.  Both listeners will fire when any part of the location changes.

Comment: Thank you qbix! but, doesnt the addValueEventListener occur only once when the image is cropped? How does the program check more than once after cropping an image? is there a way to make it run only once?